# Is there an R function that will allow me to gather conditionally?

Tags: r, tidyr, data-cleaning, data-conversion

I have a dataframe like this (in the variables IV1-IV5 I have stored the questionnaire position of target items (F1, TI1, TI2, LI1, LI2) – which in turn contain ratings):

```
  SUBJECT EXP IV1 IV2 IV3 IV4 IV5 F1 TI1 TI2 LI1 LI2
1       1   n TI2 LI1  F1 LI2 TI1 25  75  75  50  50
2       2   n LI1 TI2 LI2  F1 TI1 30  70  70  45  45
3       3   e TI1  F1 TI2 LI2 LI1 25  70  70  50  50
```

I would like to turn this into a long dataframe, like this:

```
     SUBJECT    EXP    TYPE    IV    Rating
   1       1      n     F1      3        25
   2       1      n     TI1     5        75
   3       1      n     TI2     1        50
   4       1      n     LI1     2        50
   5       1      n     LI2     4        50
   6       2      n     F1      4        30
   7       2      n     TI1     5        70
   8       2      n     TI2     2        70
   9       2      n     LI1     1        45
  10       2      n     LI2     3        45
  11       3      e     F1      2        25
  12       3      e     TI1     1        70
  13       3      e     TI2     3        70
  14       3      e     LI1     5        50
  15       3      e     LI2     4        50
```

I am aware of gather() but I don't think it can do this conversion by itself. Is there anything quicker than writing my own bunch of ifelse-statements?

A thought I had was to make a new column and conditionally unite() two cells (for every TI col unite the rating with the IV-col name that has the matching value) and then gather() across those combined columns just to separate afterwards). But it seems so tedious for something – I'm convinced – must be a common problem. Any pointers would help – Thank you!

Edit: My MWE wasn't as representative of my problem as it should have been. I changed some things in the two examples DFs above.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I screwed that up a little bit.

Comment: In the output F1 is the first value under IV3 (this is where the '3' is coming from) and the rating '25' is the first value in F1. In the input df, the variables F1, TI1, TI2, LI1 and LI2 contain the ratings for questionnaire items. IV1-5 (for 'internal variable') contain the locations of the questionnaire items. The output should be, a long df with one rating/observation per row and its location within the questionnaire in a separate column.

Comment: I suppose, F1, IV3, 25 instead of  F1, 3, 25 would be a clearer way of showing the desired output with the second row being TI1, IV5, 75.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I was able to come up with. I understand gather() much better, pivot_longer() kept throwing errors.

```
df1 <- df %>%
  gather("TYPE", "RATING", -SUBJECT, -EXP, -IV1, -IV2, -IV3, -IV4, -IV5) %>%
  gather("POS", "foobar", -SUBJECT, -EXP, -TYPE, -RATING) %>%
  filter(TYPE == foobar) %>%
  select(-foobar)
```

This is a preliminary result I can live with (and clean up a little as needed):

```
SUBJECT EXP TYPE RATING POS
      1   n  TI2     75 IV1
      1   n  LI1     50 IV2
      1   n   F1     25 IV3
      1   n  LI2     50 IV4
      1   n  TI1     75 IV5
      2   n  LI1     45 IV1
      2   n  TI2     70 IV2
      2   n  LI2     45 IV3
      2   n   F1     30 IV4
      2   n  TI1     70 IV5
      3   e  TI1     70 IV1
      3   e   F1     25 IV2
      3   e  TI2     70 IV3
      3   e  LI2     50 IV4
      3   e  LI1     50 IV5
```

I'll gladly accept suggestions for improvement. Thanks so far go to Ronak Shah's for their guidance.

Comment: Using `pivot_longer` you could do this as : `df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = F1:LI2, names_to = 'TYPE', values_to = 'RATING') %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('IV'), names_to = 'POS', values_to = 'foobar') %>%
  filter(TYPE == foobar) %>%
  select(-foobar)`